# How to enable a dynamic whatsthis-string in Qt using QWhatsThis?

Tags: c++, qt

In order to have a dynamic what's this string for a widget in Qt the following almost works (following the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-tooltips-example.html ):

```
class MyEdit : public QLineEdit {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  bool event(QEvent*e) {
    if (e && e->type() == QEvent::WhatsThis) {
      if (QHelpEvent *helpEvent = reinterpret_cast<QHelpEvent *>(e)) {
       QWhatsThis::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), "My text...");
       return true;
      }
    }
    return QLineEdit::event(e);
  }
};
```

Activating what's this for the window and clicking on the widget shows "My text" (the actual text is more complicated).

Issues:

- Activating what's this for the window and **hovering** over this widget shows a dead cursor
- Shift-F1 does not work inside the widget.

The first issue could be worked around by calling `setWhatsThis("Dummy text");` with a non-empty string, but it feels like a hack and Shift-F1 in this widget shows "Dummy text".

Is there a non-hack way of handling it - especially so that it will not be broken by updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles on this issue the following seems to handle the Shift-F1:

```
class MyEdit : public QLineEdit {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  bool event(QEvent*e) {
    if (e && e->type() == QEvent::WhatsThis) {
      if (QHelpEvent *helpEvent = reinterpret_cast<QHelpEvent *>(e)) {
       QWhatsThis::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), "My text...");
       return true;
      }
    }
    if (e && e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
      if (QKeyEvent *qk = reinterpret_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e)) {
        if (qk->key() == Qt::Key_F1 && (qk->modifiers()&Qt::ShiftModifier)) {
          QWhatsThis::showText(w.mapToGlobal(w.inputMethodQuery(Qt::ImCursorRectangle).toRect().center()), "My text...");
          qk->accept();
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return QLineEdit::event(e);
  }
};
```

and combined with calling `setWhatsThis("Dummy text");` also the hovering-part. However, it is not an elegant solution.